# find position of bracket in a string

Tags: r

I'm looking to find the position of a bracket within a string.

```
mystring <- "VAR_c(1:9)_XYZ"
```

I'd like to find the position of "(".

Comment: Related: [find position of a character in string r](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=find+position+of+a+character+in+string+r&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) and [How to search for strings with parentheses in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56174805/how-to-search-for-strings-with-parentheses-in-r)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `gregexpr` to find your bracket (Note you should add `\\` to find the bracket) with `unlist`, if you have multiple brackets it will show all the positions, like this:

```r
mystring <- "VAR_c(1:9)_XYZ"
unlist(gregexpr('\\(', mystring))
#> [1] 6
```

Example with another bracket to show it will give you all the positions like this:

```r
mystring2 <- "VAR_c(1:9)_XYZ("
unlist(gregexpr('\\(', mystring2))
#> [1]  6 15
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

split the string to a vector of characters, then use grep to find the character "("  (which has to be escaped, hence the `\\`) in this vector.

```
grep("\\(", strsplit(mystring, "")[[1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could look for a sub-string that ends with `"("` and then count how long that string is using `nchar()`. The `(.*\\()` matches a string of any characters that ends with an open bracket.  The `.*` after indicates that there may be other characters following the open bracket, but that those should not be captured.  The `gsub()` function does replacement, so what you're really doing is replacing the full string with the sub-string that ends with an open bracket.  Using `"\\1"` in the replacement argument means you want to replace the string with the match of the sub-string in the first set of un-escaped brackets, in this case `.*\\(`.

```r
mystring <- "VAR_c(1:9)_XYZ"
nchar(gsub("(.*\\().*", "\\1", mystring))
#> [1] 6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the answers above, if you want to find multiple occurences you can use `stri_locate_all()` from the `stringi` package:

```
stringi::stri_locate_all(regex = "\\(", "VAR_c(1:9)_(XYZ")
```

or faster for simple patterns like yours above:

```
stringi::stri_locate_all(fixed = "(", "VAR_c(1:9)_(XYZ")
```

Comment: Probably the `stringr` version `str_locate_all("VAR_c(1:9)_XYZ(", "\\(")` is more appropriate since `stringi` is used as backend